# Getting data from a Magento Collection

Tags: php, magento, collections, magic-function

I have a collection that has one row of data in it. If I do following,

```
$collection->getData();
```

it give me an array like below,

```
  array(1) {
    [0] => array(3) {
       ["id"] => string(1) "1"
       ["field1"] => string(10) "Field 1 Data"
       ["field2"] => string(10) "Field 2 Data"
    }
  }
```

But when I do `$collection->getField1()` it says Undefined Method. As far as I know php magic getter should work like this. Isnt it?

Any Ideas how to get this value without a foreach construct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The magic getter and setter methods only apply to Magento objects that inherit from `Varien_Object`.  In practices that's Models, and Blocks.  A collection is neither a model or a block.  A collection is a `foreach`able object that contains 0 - N model objects.

A collection's `getData` method will return the raw PHP array of each model in the collection.

```
#File: lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php
public function getData()
{
    if ($this->_data === null) {
        $this->_renderFilters()
             ->_renderOrders()
             ->_renderLimit();
        $this->_data = $this->_fetchAll($this->_select);
        $this->_afterLoadData();
    }
    return $this->_data;
}
```

What you probably want to do is grab the first model from the collection, and then grab its data.

```
$data = $collection->getFirstItem()->getData();
$field1 = $collection->getFirstItem()->getField1();
```

Comment: $data = $collection->getFirstItem()->getData(); is what I was looking for. Thanks